# How can I read multiple sensor data with blynk app and python?

Tags: python, esp32, micropython, blynk

I am trying to connect a bunch of sensors on my ESP32. I want to connect it to the Blynk app in order to get some data on my phone.

I am currently coding on python, however, I have an issue.

The code seems to always stop after it reads the light sensor. Basically, I only get the data from the light sensor and it loops from there.

Any clue what is wrong with the code?

```
import network
from time import sleep
import machine
import onewire, ds18x20
import dht
from machine import Pin
import blynklib_mp as blynklib

"""--- Connect to WiFi ---"""
WIFI_SSID = 'SSID'
WIFI_PASS = 'PASS'
BLYNK_AUTH = 'AUTH'

print("Connecting to WiFi network '{}'".format(WIFI_SSID))
wifi = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(True)
wifi.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS)
while not wifi.isconnected():
    sleep(0.1)
    print('.', end="")

print('\nWiFi IP:', wifi.ifconfig()[0])

"""--- Connect to Blynk Server ---"""
print("Connecting to Blynk server...")
blynk = blynklib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)


"""--- Settings ---""" 

#LIGHT
light_PIN = 35
blynk_VPIN_Light = 0
light_RAW = machine.ADC(machine.Pin(light_PIN))
light_RAW.atten(machine.ADC.ATTN_11DB)

#MOISTURE
moisture_PIN = 34
blynk_VPIN_Moisture = 1
moisture_RAW = machine.ADC(machine.Pin(moisture_PIN))               
moisture_RAW.atten(machine.ADC.ATTN_11DB)
moisture_PWM_PIN = 25
moisture_RAW_MIN = 20
moisture_RAW_MAX = 3600

#SOIL TEMPERATURE
soil_temperature_PIN = 4
blynk_VPIN_Soil_Temp = 2
ds_pin = machine.Pin(soil_temperature_PIN)
soil_temperature_RAW = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))
roms = soil_temperature_RAW.scan()

#AIR TEMPERATURE HUMIDITY
blynk_VPIN_Air_Temp = 3
blynk_VPIN_Air_Hum = 4
sensor = dht.DHT22(Pin(33))



@blynk.handle_event('read V{}'.format(blynk_VPIN_Light))
def read_handler(vpin):

    """--- Light Sensor ---""" 
    #WHILE LOOP
    print('Light RAW: ',light_RAW.read())
    sleep(1)
    blynk.virtual_write(blynk_VPIN_Light, light_RAW.read())

    """--- Moisture Sensor ---""" 
    #WHILE LOOP
    moisture_PWM = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(moisture_PWM_PIN), freq=600, duty=512)       #Send a PWM signal of 600 kHz to pin 25 with a dutycycle of 50%
    sleep(0.2)                                                                          #Allow the circuit to stabilize 
    moisture_Cumulative_RAW = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        moisture_Cumulative_RAW = moisture_Cumulative_RAW + moisture_RAW.read()         #Read data from analog pin 34 and add it to MoistLevel variable
        sleep(0.05)
        if moisture_RAW.read() < moisture_RAW_MIN:
            moisture_RAW_MIN = moisture_RAW.read()
        if moisture_RAW.read() > moisture_RAW_MAX:
            moisture_RAW_MAX = moisture_RAW.read()

    moisture_Average_RAW = moisture_Cumulative_RAW / 20

    moisture_PERC = (1 - (moisture_Average_RAW - moisture_RAW_MIN) / (moisture_RAW_MAX - moisture_RAW_MIN))*100
    print('Soil Moisture: ' + str(moisture_PERC) + '%')

    moisture_PWM.deinit()
    blynk.virtual_write(blynk_VPIN_Moisture, moisture_PERC)
    


    """--- Soil Temperature Sensor ---""" 
    #WHILE LOOP
    soil_temperature_RAW.convert_temp()
    sleep(0.750)
    for rom in roms:
        #print(rom)
        print("Soil Temperarture: ", soil_temperature_RAW.read_temp(rom))
    sleep(1)
    blynk.virtual_write(blynk_VPIN_Soil_Temp, soil_temperature_RAW.read_temp(rom))


    """--- Air Temperature/Humidity Sensor ---""" 
    try:
        sleep(2)
        sensor.measure()
        temp = sensor.temperature()
        hum = sensor.humidity()
        print('Air Temperature: %3.1f C' %temp)
        print('Air Humidity: %3.1f %%' %hum)
    except OSError as e:
        print('Failed to read sensor.')

    print(" ")
    blynk.virtual_write(blynk_VPIN_Air_Temp, temp)
    blynk.virtual_write(blynk_VPIN_Air_Hum, hum)

while True:
    blynk.run()
    sleep(5)
```